# Foundation 5 bower workflow

Tags: git, deployment, zurb-foundation, bower

I am starting a new project at the moment using Foundation 5.

Since the SASS-Version of Foundation 5 is using Bower as a package manager by default, there is a bower_components directory in my project's root.

Surprisingly however said bower_components directory is inside the gitignore.

Is there any specific reason for that?

If I deploy my project directly from git via a Capistrano task, all my js and css assets are gone.

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit the .gitignore file remove the entry for "bower_components", or modify your capistrano deploy task to run `bower install` on each server during the deployment.

The accepted practice is to not check bower packages into source control, just like you don't check your Gems into source control. For most Ruby/Rails projects, a `bundle install` is done during the deployment if using bundler. Same idea with Bower. Just run `bower install` from Capistrano.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove it from .gitignore.

I would also encourage you to consider checking in your `bower_components` folder. This makes your deployment fast and you're dev environment will be identical to prod. What if some dependency suddenly stops working or maybe even unpublished. Then you will deploy a broken site. Until Bower gets [shrinkwrap](https://npmjs.org/doc/shrinkwrap.html) functionality checking in bower components would be a good idea.

Recommend blog post: [Checking in front-end dependencies](http://addyosmani.com/blog/checking-in-front-end-dependencies/)